# Why calls to seekToBeginning and seekToEnd APIs of Kafka hang forever?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

My environment:

- Kafka version: `kafka_2.10-0.10.0.0`
- Kafka Java API version (client): `kafka-clients-0.10.0.0`

My configurations:

- Topic: `event_notification`
- Partitions: `20`
- Client consumer thread: `1`
- Consumer group id: `event_cg01`
- Auto Commit Flag: `false`

As per a requirement, during startup of my app, based on a flag, I have to set the offset either to **beginning**, or **end**. For this I am using following code:

```
final List<PartitionInfo> partitionsInfos = kafkaConsumer.partitionsFor(this.topic);

final List<TopicPartition> assignedPartitions = FluentIterable
      .from(partitionsInfos)                                                             
      .filter(Predicates.notNull())
      .transform(new Function<PartitionInfo, TopicPartition>() {                                                           
          @Override
          public TopicPartition apply(final PartitionInfo input) {                                                                         
            return new TopicPartition(topic, input.partition());
          }
      }).toList();

switch (listenMode) {
case OLDEST:
  kafkaConsumer.seekToBeginning(assignedPartitions);
  break;
case LATEST:
  kafkaConsumer.seekToEnd(assignedPartitions);
  break;
default:
  break;
}
```

This code is not working as expected. It hangs forever on `seekToBeginning` and `seekToEnd` calls.

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 5):

Before you can `seek()` you first need to `subscribe()` to a topic or `assign()` partition of a topic to the consumer. Please note, that `subscribe()` and `assign()` are lazy calls therefore, you also need to do a "**dummy call**" to `poll()` before you can use seek() or `seekToBeginning()` or `seekToEnd()`.

Comment: What does the dummy call to poll() look like? Is it a call to poll for zero microseconds? Why is a dummy call needed?

Comment: @JonathanM `poll(0)` does not work for me, but `poll(1)` does. As to why, the arg doc gives a hint: `If 0, returns immediately with any records that are available currently in the buffer, else returns empty. `